# Win10, BSOD with Critical_Process_Died, dump creation hangs on 0%

Tags: windows-10, bsod, dump

I am receiving BSOD with Critical_Process_Died on my Win. Dump is enabled, but the system hangs on 0%.
My system SSD looks to be ok, sfc /scannow also doesn't find any integrity violations. Any advises where to dig next?

> Can you get a minidump even?

Nope, nothing.

> Does Blue screen of death (STOP error) information in dump files. show anything?

There are no dumps.

> Is there anything in the Event Viewer?

The last events are 2 DNS Client Events (Neme resolution timed out). The next is when I reboot my system: Operation system started at system time

Comment: Can you get a minidump even?  Anything under `\windows\minidump\`?

Comment: Does [Blue screen of death (STOP error) information in dump files.](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) show anything?

Comment: Is there anything in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Get your PC manufacturer's test application and test all the hardware (not just the SSD).  Also run DISM before running SFC.  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then SFC again when DISM has completed.  Restart and see if there is any change

Comment: @HelpingHand l I've answered your questions in my initial question to clarify it.

Comment: @davidpostill I've answered your questions in my initial question to clarify it.

Comment: Change the crash dump to a mini dump instead of the full dump. Control panel>System>Advanced system settings>Start up and Recovery settings. Does it store a crash file now? C:\Windows\System32\minidump

Comment: `Neme resolution timed out` should be `Name resolution timed out`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the solution was outside my OS. After changing my CMOS battery the OS began to work normally. Symptoms were a bit odd for that type of malfunction but that really helped!